# Probability and stat

Tags: probability

A group of eight people decide to use the “Secret Santa” method so that each person buys another one a Christmas present. To this end, each writes their name on a piece of paper, and all names are placed in a hat. Then, each person draws a piece of paper from the hat. If someone draws their own name, all names are placed back in the hat, and drawn again, until success.

What is the probability that the method succeeds with just one draw? In other words, what is the probability that no one draws their own name in just one draw?

Comment: first person not drawing his name=7/8, 2nd person=6/8 and goes on till last person which is 1/8 so would it be like (1/8*2/8*3/8*...*7/8)=prob

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With n people,

The probability of not drawing your own name is

```
(n-1) / n
```

The probability of n people not drawing their own names is

```
((n-1) / n)^ n
```

But that's only if you put the names back into the hat after they're drawn.

If you don't put the names back, which would be the real world example, it would be

```
((n-1)/n)) * ((n-2)/(n-1)) * ((n-3)/(n-2)) * etc * (1/2)
```

Comment: so you mean the probability that no one draws their own name in just one draw without putting back into hat is ((8-1)/8)^8 ??

Comment: No, you may have missed the edits. That would be if they did put them back.

Comment: isn't is ((n-1) / n)^ n?

Comment: Upvoted, you have elegantly described both the cases. Keep up doing the good job... Ask OP to accept the answer.

Comment: No, it's the last line I wrote, which is incomplete and would need to be filled out for a specific n